# WCF Service Application does not work with App pool in integrated Pipeline mode

Tags: wcf, iis, svc

I am running the Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate. For testing purposes I deployed the WCF Service Application from the VS Template without modifications on the Default Website. Retrieving the Service1.svc only works if the App pool is in Classic Pipeline Mode but not in the Integrated one.
If I switch to integrated mode I get a HTTP-Error 404.17 - Not Found.

The Isapi Handler to aspnet_isapi.dll for the *.svc extension is registered for 32 and 64 bit as well. The Service works in classic mode. So the handler registration seems to be partly right.

I already tried setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to True. Deploying the Application as 32bit or 64 bit made no differnece neither.

What am I missing?